# BeanUtils.copyProperties (Ignorar mais de um campo)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

tudo bem? Estou utilizando java e Spring-framework em um projeto restful, então criei a seguinte classe:

```
Categoria 

    (id, descrição, dtCadastro, dtAlteração)
```

Na classe estou utilizando as anotações `@PrePersist` e `@PreUpdate` para os campos de data, assim eles são atualizados automaticamente quando eu  persisto um novo objeto ou quando atualizo um objeto já existente.

Na aplicação manipulo os objetos deste tipo utilizando um DTO (CategoriaDTO) com os seguintes atributos:

```
(id, descrição)
```

Os campos de datas foram omitidos por serem campos utilizados para auditoria dos dados persistidos, não sendo manipulados pelo cliente.

O problema é que quando utilizo BeanUtils.copyProperties em um end Point de atualização ele acaba gerando nulo nos campos de data, devido o DTO não possuir estes campos.

BeanUtils.copyProperties também tem uma assinatura que permite ignorar um campo, estou utilizando ele para ignorar o id no processo de atualização.

```
 BeanUtils.copyProperties(dto, dtoAtualizado, "id");
```

Existe alguma classe que tenha um método semelhante (copiar valores dos campos para outro objeto) porém que permita ignorar mais de um campo?

Obrigado pelos retornos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade houve uma utilização equivocada de minha parte. O método `copy.Pproperties()` consegue ignorar mais de um campo. Para isso, basta você continuar inserindo os campos separados por vírgula, ou seja, a classe atende a necessidade da aplicação.